# Kitkat kills: Not allowed to load local resource: file:///android_asset/webkit/android-weberror.png

Tags: android, android-webview

I have an app that uses WebViews. I've changed my targetAPI from 18 to 19 and I'm currently testing on the new 4.4. For some reason I'm getting this error: `Not allowed to load local resource: file:///android_asset/webkit/android-weberror.png` on 4.4 but not on 4.3, does somebody have clue why?

Since I don't really know where to start looking I can't give the complete code. It might have something to do with the `shouldInterceptRequest(Webview, String)` method in the WebViewClient but I'm not really sure. If I know more, I'll update the question.

Comment: How are you loading the initial page? Is it from a server or is it a html file in the APK?

Comment: @rahulritesh not really, it had something to do with shouldInterceptRequest but I didn't find the right solution so I've decided to take another approach...

Comment: Can you please tell me what you did? I am unable to load my cached data in my app, with Android 4.4

Comment: I had this same problem when I forgot to turn on my WiFi, so you might just need to make sure you have an internet connection.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"Not allowed to load local resource" is a security origin error. The KitKat WebView has stronger security restrictions and it seems like these are kicking in. FWIW I tried just loading a file:///android_asset URL and it worked fine.

Did you call any of the file-related WebSettings APIs (like setAllowFileAccess(false)) by any chance? Are you trying to load the resource from an https: URL?

Comment: How to load local html file from sdcard in kitkat?

Comment: @marcin.kosiba What is the solution for https? Thanks.

Comment: @AdamSilver - use shouldInterceptRequest to host your local resources on an https:// URL.

Comment: Turns out setAllowFileAccess is disabled by default, setting it to true worked for me

Answer (score 25):

I found that I had this problem on KitKat when I used `webview.loadData()`. If I instead used `webview.loadDataWithBaseURL()` (I used "file:///android_asset/" as the baseURL), then the problem went away.

The methods `setAllowFileAccess()`, `setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs()`, and `setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs()` did not have any affect that I could see.

Comment: There's a note at the bottom of of those `allow...` methods in [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(boolean)) that says: 
> Note that this setting affects only JavaScript access to file scheme resources. Other access to such resources, for example, from image HTML elements, is unaffected.


Question is how *do* you affect HTML elements!?

Comment: Thanks ! loadDataWithBaseURL() also helped me playing local video via custom content provider ("content://myapp.something.localfiles/.../video.mp4"), which stopped working on KitKat using just loadData()

Comment: Awesome! It works like a charm. I got that issue when willing to load some static js/css files into my webview, solved using that way. Thanks!

Answer (score 22):

A bit of an intrusive hack, but I worked around this issue by introducing a "unique token" and implementing the `WebViewClient` with a `shouldInterceptRequest` override.

First, change the URL from `file:///android/asset` to a relative path with a uniquely identifying token:

```
<script src="**injection**www/scripts.js"></script>
```

Then, override `shouldInterceptRequest` as follows:

```
// Injection token as specified in HTML source
private static final String INJECTION_TOKEN = "**injection**";

webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

    @Override
    public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, String url) {
        WebResourceResponse response = super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, url);
        if(url != null && url.contains(INJECTION_TOKEN)) {
            String assetPath = url.substring(url.indexOf(INJECTION_TOKEN) + INJECTION_TOKEN.length(), url.length());
            try {
                response = new WebResourceResponse(
                        "application/javascript",
                        "UTF8",
                        getContext().getAssets().open(assetPath)
                );
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace(); // Failed to load asset file
            }
        }
        return response;
    }
});
```

This is likely to degrade WebView performance *slightly* as we are calling the `contains()` on each resource which is attempted to be loaded, but it's the only workaround I've found to this issue.

Comment: I did something similar, arrived here with the hope of a better solution, but this seems to be the best workaround. In my case I had a custom content provider for displaying images on my webview. It used to work flawlessly until KitKat, so I had to do something similar to intercept the request, and create a response with the image's inputstream.

Comment: Is there a way to apply is code to iOS > Objective C ?

Comment: `shouldInterceptRequest`  doesn't even get called on an attempt to load from "file://", before "Not allowed to load local resource" is thrown.

Comment: @Michael Exactly. This answer explicitly *replaces* the file:/// URL with a relative URL,with a token,so that the method does get called.

Answer (score 5):

HERE IS THE SOLUTION: This problem occurs when you try to load a file from library projects. If your app depends on a library where webview and html files reside, then you need include assets from that library project into main application project while compiling. For example, IntelliJ has an option to do this. In the compiler settings "Include assets from dependencies into APK", but make sure that your asset files should have different names than main application has. You don't want library project's index.html to be overridden by main app.

Answer (score 3):

The solution below works for me.

```
webview.loadDataWithBaseURL( baseUrl, htmlStr, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
```

where `baseUrl` is your external domain, not file:///android_asset/ (i.e. http://a.domain.com ).

Comment: Thank you this approach works for me (Android 5.1.1)

Answer (score 1):

It may be needed to add a permission

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

to a manifest.

This permission is enforced starting in API level 19.

Comment: This solved my problem - unlike the OP I was trying to load an html file from the sdcard and got the error "Not allowed to load local resource: file:///android_asset/webkit/android-weberror.png""

Answer (score 1):

Not available at the time, this now works (though it's not recommended):

```
webView.getSettings().setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW);
```

Here's what the doc says about setMixedContentMode:

> Configures the WebView's behavior when a secure origin attempts to load a resource from an insecure origin. By default, apps that target KITKAT or below default to MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW. Apps targeting LOLLIPOP default to MIXED_CONTENT_NEVER_ALLOW. The preferred and most secure mode of operation for the WebView is MIXED_CONTENT_NEVER_ALLOW and use of MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW is strongly discouraged.

However, this might not answer the original question; it looks like the restriction only started with Lollipop.

Comment: This particular flag affects the WebView's ability to load insecure (non-HTTPs) assets on a page served over HTTPs, not its ability to load local resources. Setting this to `MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW` won't enable local content to be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to handle this is by using [WebViewAssetLoader](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/webkit/WebViewAssetLoader) from [AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx) (the successor to the Android Support Library). This class makes it possible for any page element to make use of asset files.

You can add the library to your project by adding this line to your app's `build.gradle`:

```
implementation 'androidx.webkit:webkit:1.5.0'
```

Create an instance of `WebViewAssetLoader` and point it to the asset path you wish to expose to the WebView:

```kotlin
val assetLoader = WebViewAssetLoader.Builder()
    .addPathHandler("/some/path/", AssetsPathHandler(context))
    .build()
```

Then override `WebViewClient.shouldInterceptRequest()`:

```kotlin
webView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
    override fun shouldInterceptRequest(
        view: WebView,
        request: WebResourceRequest
    ): WebResourceResponse? {
        return assetLoader.shouldInterceptRequest(request.url)
    }
}
```

Now, instead of `file:///android_asset/...`, your URLs become:

```
https://appassets.androidplatform.net/...
```

Answer (score -1):

I've found a nice workaround in this link : http://trentmilton.com/android-webview.html

A summary of the solution is something like:

```
WebView webView = new WebView(this); // this is the context
webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

Hope that helps