# Not allowed to load local resource:file:///android_asset phonegap

Tags: android, cordova

I have a page hosted online accessed that page in my phonegap application but now i want to come back to my local files in

> file:///android_asset/www/profile.html

but it gives me error:

> 08-21 14:08:00.324: E/Web Console(8304): Not allowed to load local
>   resource: file:///android_asset/www/profile.html at null:0

How do I fix this issue.

Comment: i guess you gotta open the hosted page in InApp Browser so that you can come back to app on close of InApp Browser

Comment: Did yo had a check on this?

Comment: Fixed that in 2014.

Comment: @Nico i guess you gotta open the hosted page in InApp Browser so that you can come back to app on close of InApp Browser

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19997146/kitkat-kills-not-allowed-to-load-local-resource-file-android-asset-webkit-a

Comment: May be your ans in this post, can you please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19997146/kitkat-kills-not-allowed-to-load-local-resource-file-android-asset-webkit-a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use InAppBroswer plugin for that.

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
```

Plugin found [here](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/inAppBrowser/)

Answer (score 0):

You gotta open the hosted page in InApp Browser so that you can come back to app on close of InApp Browser.

The basic working sample of InAppBroswer plugin along with returning to app on click of back button in InAppBrowser can be fonud at the following [github link](https://github.com/gandhirajan/Cordova_InAppBrowser). Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Found that you can access it through the cdvfile:// protocol as long as you have the permissions set in config.xml