# Load CSS and JS files from assets folder in android webview

Tags: javascript, android, css, webview, android-assets

I want to load CSS and JS files localy from android assets folder for better perfomance in android webview,Is it possible?
I appreciate your help,thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In **android** project

```
WebView myweb = FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webView1);
myweb.LoadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
```

In **index.html**

```
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

And if you need to increase android webview performance and graphic change this properties

```
myweb.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
myweb.Settings.DisplayZoomControls = false;
myweb.Settings.SetRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.High);
if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.Kitkat)
{
   myweb.SetLayerType(Android.Views.LayerType.Hardware, null);
}
```

if you are using android studio : view this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152422/webview-load-html-from-assets-directory)

if you need only js or css files view this Answers:

- [Load CSS JS from Assets folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47733553/load-css-js-from-assets-folder)
- [Android - How to load external javascript files within at runtime generated HTML data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27845287/android-how-to-load-external-javascript-files-within-at-runtime-generated-html)
- [Android webview, loading javascript file in assets folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5649111/android-webview-loading-javascript-file-in-assets-folder)

Comment: thx for your answer,but I only want to load CSS and JS not the entire website.

Comment: i didn't get you , you need to load js and css to A page already exists in webview