# WebView problems in Kitkat device

Tags: android, webview, webviewclient

I'm trying to create webView app, i'm testing in API 19 kitkat 4.4. When I run the code, i'm getting this message `Not allowed to load local resource: file:///android_asset/webkit/android-weberror.png`. Before i'm using kitkat device, it's worked well on 4.3 device.

```
webView = (WebView) getView().findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());
        webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
        webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");`

`private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
```

Can you tell me what should i do to solve this?

Comment: The best practice is use and HTML with image embedded, no call directly the image

Comment: did you try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19997146/kitkat-kills-not-allowed-to-load-local-resource-file-android-asset-webkit-a) solution ?