# WebView in Android StrictMode policy violation; ms: android.os.StrictMode$StrictModeDiskReadViolation: policy=287 violation=2

Tags: android, webview

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    View view = findViewById(R.id.button);
    final WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());
    view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String url = editText.getText().toString();
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
            webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
            webView.loadUrl(url);
        }
    });
}

private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient{
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}
```

}

Error status
Got the error as "Not allowed to load local resource: file:///android_asset/webkit/android-weberror.png", source: data:text/html,chromewebdata (12)"

Comment: Did you google this error before posting? Seems to be a dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19997146/kitkat-kills-not-allowed-to-load-local-resource-file-android-asset-webkit-a

Comment: possible duplicate of [Kitkat kills: Not allowed to load local resource: file:///android\_asset/webkit/android-weberror.png](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19997146/kitkat-kills-not-allowed-to-load-local-resource-file-android-asset-webkit-a)

Comment: I referred the forum in stack overflow which discussed the same. But still i could not fix it

Comment: from the above link, i followed like  webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
                webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(url, "data", "text/html", "UTF-8", ""); but still its not working

Comment: @BrightVarghese: try `webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);`

Comment: @BNK Still i am not getting the expected result

Comment: Try load like this `webView.loadDataWithBaseURL( "file:///android_asset/", html, "text/html", 
"utf-8", null ); `

Comment: I got an error as "MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!" when i m running the emulator. No result

Comment: getting an error in emulator as net::ERR_CACHE_MISS

Comment: I got the solution                                                                                      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>  instead of <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.internet"/>