# Facebook token auth fails on Android but not browsers

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm building an ionic app and I'm using ng-token-auth. Everything is fine in a browser, I can identify via Facebook, but when I emulate on android, I got an error after I get logged into Facebook and the app is redirecting :

```
I/chromium( 2252): [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Not allowed to load local resource: file:///android_asset/www/index.html?auth_token=kUDlceeLBDmauQ2nN_KzqQ&blank=true&client_id=zoIcXXXXolEkpN0IxM9utA&config=&expiry=1459541228&uid=1727512764150849#/app/signin", source: file:///android_asset/www/index.html#/app/signin (0)
```

Here is my back-end code:

`BASE_API_URL` depends if the app is launched on locahost or not.

```
$authProvider
  .configure({
    apiUrl: BASE_API_URL,
    storage: 'localStorage',
    forceHardRedirect: true,
    omniauthWindowType: window.cordova == undefined ? 'sameWindow' : 'inAppBrowser',
    authProviderPaths: {
      facebook: '/auth/facebook'
    }
  })
```

My config.xml has the inAppBrowser feature.

```
<feature name="InAppBrowser">
  <param name="ios-package" value="CDVInAppBrowser"/>
  <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser.InAppBrowser"/>
</feature>
```

Any idea ? does it have to do something with [webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19997146/kitkat-kills-not-allowed-to-load-local-resource-file-android-asset-webkit-a#tab-top) ? Or is it the Content-Security-Policy ? I use InAppBrowser feature, but how could I be sure it's launched with ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I solved it. It was due to `omniauthWindowType: window.cordova == undefined ? 'sameWindow' : 'inAppBrowser'` that always used `sameWindow`.