# Cordova with Visual Studio for Android

Tags: android, cordova, visual-studio-cordova

I am creating a Cross platform app with Apache Cordova tools for Visual Studio (taco). the application displays HTML pages from web server and the page is using JavaScript that are stored locally on the device. it works fine on windows phone. But in Android I am getting the following exception

**Not allowed to load local resource: file:///ANDROID_ASSET/www/scripts/common.js**

Is there any configuration setting to make this work?

EDIT:
@Elvis Xia, I am trying to retrive the following HTML page from the server in my cordova application. In this page some scripts tag has src pointing to the local javascript file on the device using FILE:///ANDROID_ASSET/www/ path. but it is not working on android.
For windows application I am referencing the local javascript using ms-appx-web://com.appname/www/ path and that works fine on windows.

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
<head>
    <title>Test Apps</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="scripts/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />

        <script type="text/javascript" src="FILE:///ANDROID_ASSET/www/cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="FILE:///ANDROID_ASSET/www/scripts/platformOverrides.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="FILE:///ANDROID_ASSET/www/scripts/common.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/index.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div data-role="page">

            <div data-role="header">
                <h1>Apps</h1>
            </div>
            <!-- /header -->

            <div data-role="content">
                <p>
                    <div>
                        <button id="btnOpt1">Option 1</button>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <button id="btnOpt2">Option 2</button>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <button id="btnOpt3">Option 3</button>
                    </div>
                </p>
            </div>
            <!-- /content -->

            <div data-role="footer">
                <h4>Page Footer</h4>
            </div>
            <!-- /footer -->
        </div>
        <!-- /page -->

    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Comment: Please refer this [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19997146/1825578), it seems question is same

Comment: Thanks Nitish.. but that solution wont work for me because I am writing Cordova app using Visual Studio tools for Apache Cordova. The other solution is for regular Android app with WebView.

Comment: OK, try to put this in your config.xml `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

Comment: Could you give more information about how to reproduce this problem? ex: what plugins you are using and maybe some codes.

Comment: @NitishkumarSingh it didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to implement the solution provided in this [Kitkat kills: Not allowed to load local resource: file:///android_asset/webkit/android-weberror.png](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19997146/kitkat-kills-not-allowed-to-load-local-resource-file-android-asset-webkit-a) (Thanks nitishkumar for your suggestion)
but instead of updating the activity, I created a cordova plugin with "onload =true" and implemented similar solution. so I just have to add the plugin to the project. seems to be working fine. I'll post if I find any issue.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the file:// protocol on Android, you should be able to reference your script file as a relative path. If your HTML file is located in the `www` folder, then you can reference your `common.js` script using the following:

```
<script src="scripts/common.js"></script>
```

This same script tag would then work on all the platforms you target using Cordova.

Comment: Thanks for your response...But when the html file is coming from a web server, the relative paths would be pointing to the server location...not the local file. for example if the html file is from http://webapp.somedomain.com/, the src path "scripts/common.js would be pointing to http://webapp.somedomain.com/scripts/common.js