# Xamarin Android Webview: Not allowed to load local resource "file:///android_asset/*.css" source: (1)?

Tags: android, xamarin, webview, assets

I have a small CSS file I use with JavaScript to override the CSS on a website loaded in a WebView.  I would like to load it locally instead of need to access it online.  I have gotten the JavaScript to work perfectly when the file is uploaded to a temporary filehost, so it works fine, but something regarding permissions won't let me use it as an asset.

I've tried setting permissions, changing the WebView's settings to allow MixedContentMode always, tried using LoadData, etc, but it always throws the "Not allowed" issue.  The asset has the AndroidAsset build action.

```
string jsToInject = "javascript: var link=document.createElement('link');link.href='file:///android_asset/newsOverride.css';link.type ='text/css'; link.rel ='stylesheet';document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link);";

view.LoadUrl(jsToInject);
```

When the link.href field is set to the file hosted on the web somewhere, it loads the CSS as expected.  But when it's selected as an asset it simply throws 
`I/chromium(11626): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Not allowed to load local resource: file:///android_asset/newsOverride.css", source:  (1)`

All I've been able to find on the error is with Xamarin Forms, not Xamarin Android, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to implementing the WebViewClient with a shouldInterceptRequest override like this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19997146/kitkat-kills-not-allowed-to-load-local-resource-file-android-asset-webkit-a/20992306#20992306

Comment: That did it.  It had been falling into the catch block but that was because you don't need file:///android_asset/ before the asset filename in Xamarin.  What a weird workaround.

Comment: Yes, that is weird, did you solve this issue? If so, can I post my comment to answer and accept it? Helps other searching for questions to help on so they don't waste time on questions that are answered. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it's working as it should.  Go ahead and post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue should implementing the WebViewClient with a `shouldInterceptRequest` override like this thread.
[Kitkat kills: Not allowed to load local resource: file:///android_asset/webkit/android-weberror.png](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19997146/kitkat-kills-not-allowed-to-load-local-resource-file-android-asset-webkit-a/20992306#20992306)

Comment: Code snippet for Xamarin.Android, overriding CSS:  


`public override WebResourceResponse ShouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, string url)  
    {  
    WebResourceResponse response = base.ShouldInterceptRequest(view, url);  
    if (url != null && url.Contains(INJECTION_TOKEN))  
    {  
        string AssetPath = "newsOverride.css";  
        response = new WebResourceResponse("text/css", "UTF-8", context.Assets.Open(AssetPath));  
    }  
    return response;  
    }`